# Different back space handling in different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This controller is for page1.html

```
test1.controller('test1Controller', function($scope,$document) {

$document.on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"){ 
           confirm("you are In Home page");
        }
    });

}
```

This controller is for page2.html

```
test2.controller('test2Controller', function($scope,$document) {

$document.on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"){ 
           //HERE CODE LOGIC SHOULD COME TO PREVIOUS PAGE
        }
    });
```

}

I entered data in page1 and moved to page2.html and click on backspace of keyboard,
Although i am on second page,function in test1Controller is getting invoked.

What is wrong with the above logic..

With the current above code,both the functions in two different controllers are being invoked.

Comment: You're adding a binding to the document which doesn't get reloaded on page change so the binding is still there, if you navigate to the second page and refresh this should only call the function on the second page. To fix this look into [unbinding](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: @GeorgeLee..Is there alternative in angular js rather than using jquery..thanks

Comment: Angular uses JQueryLite...[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 1):

Unbind all keydown events before you bind the new one in your controllers by doing

**For controller one**

```
    test1.controller('test1Controller', function($scope,$document) {

    $document.off('keydown')

    $document.on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"){ 
           confirm("you are In Home page");
        }
    });

}
```

**For controller two**

```
test2.controller('test2Controller', function($scope,$document) {

    $document.off('keydown')

    $document.on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"){ 
            //HERE CODE LOGIC SHOULD COME TO PREVIOUS PAGE
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: I am very much new to front end (javascript/front end frameworks)..So i am assuming that u are saying similar to creation of new instance of class in backend(java)..If possible code snippet would be of great help..Thanks and cheers

Comment: we are not using ui route scope in angular so problem is all the controllers are loaded initally..rather than being loaded dynamically..so i tried in the way u specified above.i think it will work absolutely fine when we will use ui route scope..Is there any other alternative if we are not using ui route scope? Thanks